# Windows resizing jumps instead going smoothly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have problem when trying to implement custom button for window resizing. This video show's what happening http://screencast.com/t/Dtl5PyLcN3TE

I use thumb element to implement custom resizing button for window.

```
  <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle}" DragStarted="Thumb_OnDragStarted" DragDelta="Thumb_OnDragDeltanDragDelta"/>
```

And it's code behind

```
 private void Thumb_OnDragDeltanDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        LogWindow.Height = m_BaseSize.Y + e.VerticalChange;
        LogWindow.Width = m_BaseSize.X + e.HorizontalChange;
    }

    private void Thumb_OnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_BaseSize.X = LogWindow.Width;
        m_BaseSize.Y = LogWindow.Height;
    }
```

How to make custom resizing more simmilar to native implementation?

**EDIT:**
Looks like i understand what's the problem. Thumb_OnDragDeltanDragDelta get invalid vertical change some times

Comment: Try to explain your actual issue in the question. Even the video isn't clear what the problem is

Comment: In short window don't resizing smoothly, it jumps

Comment: looks normal to me. Have you tried on other applications/windows, is there any differences?

Comment: @Bolu try to resize notepad youl see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I no longer rely on the data from this event, and use mouse coordinates. All looks good now.

```
 private void Thumb_OnDragDeltanDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
        Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        var hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual((Visual)sender) as HwndSource;
        Matrix transformToDevice = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
        Point[] p = { new Point(Left, Top), new Point(position.X, position.Y) };
        transformToDevice.Transform(p);
        SetWindowPos(hwndSource.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, Convert.ToInt32(p[0].X), Convert.ToInt32(p[0].Y), Convert.ToInt32(p[1].X), Convert.ToInt32(p[1].Y), SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
```

And use winApi resize

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

    [Flags]
    public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
    {
        SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,

        SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,

        SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,

        SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,

        SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,

        SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,

        SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,

        SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,

        SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,

        SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,

        SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,

        SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,

        SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,

        SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,

        SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,
    }
```